# Unable to get other user's photo thumbnail using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: office365, onedrive, office365api, office-js, microsoft-graph-api

According to this official document [List thumbnails for a DriveItem](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_list_thumbnails), we can get OneDrive photo thumbnails by using this API.

When I sent a request to get a photo thumbnail from my OneDrive with Microsoft Graph API, server returned 200 and worked fine.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{my user id}/drive/items/{my photo object id}/thumbnails`

However while trying to get a photo thumbmail from other user's onedrive, the server returned 404 not found.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{other user's id}/drive/items/{other user's photo id}/thumbnails`

I really sure that the **other user's photo** exists and that the id is correct.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a restriction around accessing other users' OneDrive photos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**At this point in time, it is not possible for a user to query another user's OneDrive**.

You can confirm by querying the root of the drive.

For yourself, you'll see the list of files in the drive:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{my user id}/drive/root/children
```

However, for any other user, you'll get back an empty collection (even though there are files present in that drive).

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{other user's id}/drive/root/children
```